# Android - Use map tiles offline

Tags: java, android, maps, tiles

I am using Google Maps in my application. Part of the specification is to be able to view the map offline.

I have a set of custom map tile images spanning across an area of the UK, how do I got about displaying those tiles over the google map view?

Comment: The Google APIs add-on for Android does not support offline maps. Furthermore, if you have your own tiles, why do you *need* Google Maps?

Comment: Its so i can get the location of the user via GPS and display markers at specific geo points. I know you cant save maps offline which is why i want to display an offline version when that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

CloudMade are working on an Android SDK for OpenStreetMap, that may be worth looking at as/when it arrives. I believe there are also existing open-source OSM SDKs for Android. You're likely to find much more flexibility in those solutions (and source code) compared to GMaps.

Answer (score 1):

We have created  [Nutiteq Maps SDK](http://www.nutiteq.com/map-api) which enables it also. It has GPL and commercial license options, works with OpenStreetMap and any other commercial vendors which provide tiles (Bing, Mapquest, Digitalglobe, Navteq etc)